# AuthResult task in google sign in returning false in task.isSuccess statement

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

I had implemented Google Signin with my app using Firebase.
As the user signed in, the MainActivity should start.
But this statement in my firebaseAuthWithGoogle() function is returning false as:

```
  if (task.isSuccessful()) {  
          //Start The activity from here
          }
```

Here's my login.java that is causing me this:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

private SignInButton signInButton;
private TextView textView;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.SignIn);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.negativetext);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.negativetext));

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+account, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w("Signing in: ", "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + credential, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        //FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        //Log.i("Test:", " Compiled ?");
                        //startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
                        //updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });

    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+acct, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Can anyone suggest/advice what am i doin' wrong here?
I checked the statements, so i commented some of the lines.
Any regarding advice would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: first check weather you google auth api is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are using the following line of code twice:

```
startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
```

Once in your `mAuthListener` and once in your `firebaseAuthWithGoogle()` method. You need to redirect the user to the `MainActivity` only when the `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null`, which means that the user is already authenticated. I have explained in one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwgMWBhObDw&t=3s&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=5) all the steps hat you need to follow in order the achieve the exact thing that you are looking for.